# How to delete row in Mongo collection using SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am using a MongoDB that has next collection:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class PendingState {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String receiverProfileId;
    private String senderProfileId;
    private UserAction action;
    private FollowingStatus status;
}
```

Repository looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface PendingStateRepository extends MongoRepository<PendingState, String> {
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to find a row where `receiverProfileId` is some value sent in and `senderProfileId`is some value sent in.

How can I do this?